# iCloud backup encryption security

Tags: security, encryption, icloud

From recent news in the case of unlocking one of the San Bernardino suspect's phones, Apple apparently was able to give the FBI data from the phone's most recent iCloud backup. So reading that, can one assume that the data in iCloud backups can be decrypted by Apple employees without any user passcode/key?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [security.se] might be better suited for this type of question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: The iCloud data is encrypted with an Apple supplied key so yes, Apple can access that data. If you need protection against a legal court order do not use iCloud backup.

Comment: This resource should help answer some of your questions: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/why-does-the-fbi-ask-apple-for-help-to-decrypt-an-iphone

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The iCloud data is encrypted with an Apple supplied key so yes, Apple can access that data. If you need protection against a legal court order do not use iCloud backup.

[@zaph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451475/zaph), thanks! That answered my question.